# Refering a value in a class which is in same pacakage

Tags: java

I have two classes,  `main` and `timex`. I want to display the value of a variable in my `timex` class, but I always get the answer 0.

```
public class mainaxe {

    public static void main (String arg[]) {
        timex n = new timex();

        int n2 = timex.a;
        n.timedel();
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            System.out.println("the time is :" + n2);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my timex class:

```
public class timex extends Thread{
    public static int a;

    public int timedel(){
        for(int i=0; i<200; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                a = a + 5;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){}

            // start();
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

I want to get the value from the `timex` class and use it in my `main` class to print the value for every 1 sec.

Comment: that isn't a properly constructed `Thread` if that is all the code you have, and you never call `.start()` on it in the `main` either, you have deeper problems than this.

Comment: do i have to start ? the method ..won't it work when i refer the value a ?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html).  There are several things you need to do to set up a multi-threaded program.  Right now, you are running just a single thread, and your main function calls `timedel()` and waits for it to finish.

Comment: could u please give me a code .. which will work .. for the above problem ?  just only need this  :( to finish my work

Comment: One other comment: You assign `n2` to `a` before you even start the "thread" (which isn't really a thread).  The thread then modifies `a` but that won't affect `n2` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like,

Mainaxe.java

```
package mainaxe;

public class Mainaxe {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Timex n = new Timex();
        n.start();
//        int n2 = Timex.a;
//        n.timedel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println("the time is :" + Timex.a);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Timex.java

```
package mainaxe;

public class Timex extends Thread {

    public static int a;

    public Timex() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        timedel();
    }

    public int timedel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                a = a + 5;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            // start();
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i will try this out and let u know .  i been waiting for a reply like your for my problem

Comment: Its working thank you . i will finish my project work for collage but i want to learn what i did wrong .which topic i should learn again !! really u saved my day . i guess Thread and constructor class

Comment: Basically you had issues. You should start the thread properly, by adding a run() method with the logic and then call start(). The other issue was when accessing the n2 variable (for "the time is :"), you should access the variable that actually changed. Since n2 is a primitive int it does not have reference to the changing value of Timex.a  .

Answer (score 1):

If you want a multi-threaded program, then in your class that extends `Thread`, declare a method exactly like this:

```
@Override
public void run () {
    // in here, put the code your other thread will run
}
```

Now, after you create a new object of this class:

```
timex n = new timex();
```

you have to start the thread like this:

```
n.start();
```

This causes the object to start running its `run` method in a new thread.  Having your main thread call other methods in `n` won't do anything with the new thread; any other method called by the main thread will be performed in the main thread.  So you can't communicate with the new thread with a function call.  You have to do it with other means, such as you were trying to do with your variable `a`.